# Send and receive messages to and from posix child processes?

Tags: lua, posix

I'm trying to setup a socket based server in Lua that can spin up child processes as needed to handle incoming requests (a simple http server that uses multiple forked processes rather than threading).

I'm trying to use [luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) for this task, but I don't see a way to communicate/send messages between the parent and children processes.

Comment: How about using [pipes](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/examples/fork.lua.html)? Or a [message queue](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.sys.msg.html)? You could even use [sockets](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.sys.socket.html) for interprocess communication.

Comment: Pipes looks like most similar to what I had in mind.  I just want to do a hand off from parent to child and then ignore it after that.  Once the child process is done it could shut itself down.  I see though that the message queue could be a good approach as well.  I could leave the child running once it's been forked and let it keep processing new requests off of the queue.

Sorry; this is my first time working with luaposix (or posix at all for that matter).  Is there a way for the parent to check if the child process is still alive and/or responsive?

Comment: In C, it's `waitpid` with `WNOHANG` to check process status without blocking. **luaposix** has [posix.sys.wait](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.sys.wait.html). To check responsiveness, you could "ping" it in time intervals.

Comment: @Youka, would you be willing to discuss this further in a chat room?  I have some related questions that I don't think fall in the accepted Stack Overflow question/answer format here.  

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105065/lua-child-processes